# What permissions are required to allow Lambda function to create SageMaker Batch Transform Job if bucket name doesn't include sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

Here is custom policy for calling SageMaker Batch Transform Job:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/path/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/another_path/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "sagemaker:CreateTransformJob",
        "sagemaker:DescribeTrainingJob",
        "sagemaker:DescribeTransformJob"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I also attached to the Lambda role the default AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole permissions.

If I change the bucket name to include start with *sagemaker*, everything works fine, however, I cannot do that. Do you have any suggestions about the policy and what permissions I have missed to add?

Edit

Here is error messages from SageMaker transform job logs: `# 011... 24 more2020-07-15T12:49:26.332:[sagemaker logs]: <bucket-name>/path/input_file.json: 403 Forbidden (403): Forbidden` and `2020-07-15T12:49:26.345:[sagemaker logs]: MaxConcurrentTransforms=2, MaxPayloadInMB=6, BatchStrategy=MULTI_RECORD`. There are only 2 lines in that job log group. In another log group are no errors, only messages that model was loaded for predictions.

And error message in Lambda: `Transform failed with the following error: ClientError: See job logs for more information`

Comment: Have you tried with simply `arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post actual error message? Which action and policy statement causes deny?

Comment: I updated question, model can't read input, however, I doubled checked that it has GetObject permission in that directory.